# Recursive Binary Conversion C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary

I am fairly new to C++. I am trying to write a recursive binary function. The binary output needs to be 4 bits, hence the logic around 15 and the binary string length. It converts to binary correctly, the problem I am having is ending the recursive call and returning the binary string to the main function. It seems to just backwards through the call stack? Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Assuming using namespace std. I know this is not good practice, however it is required for my course.

```
string binary(int number, string b){
    if (number > 0 && number < 15){
        int temp;
        temp = number % 2;
        b = to_string(temp) + b;
        number = number / 2;
        binary(number, b);
    }
    else if (number > 15){
        b = "1111";
        number = number - 15;
        binary(number, b);
    }
    else if (number == 15){
        b = "11110000";
        return b;
    }
    //should be if number < 1
    else{
        int s = b.size();
        //check to make sure the binary string is 4 bits or more
        if (s >= 4){
            return b;
        }
        else{
            for (int i = s; i < 4; i++){
                b = '0' + b;
            }
            return b;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should do something with the return value from `binary(number, b);` but I'm not sure what. More description of what this code is supposed to do, expected outputs for given inputs and a [mcve] please.

Comment: What is the base case for the recursion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your function returning a string, but then you require the user to supply an initialized string for you, and you throw away the return value except for the base cases of 15 and 0.  The rest of the time, your actual communication is using the parameter **b**.  This multiple communication will cause some headaches.

I also note that you return a properly padded 4-bit number in *normal* cases; however, you force a return an 8-bit **15** for the exact value 15.  Is this part of the assignment specification?

The logic for larger numbers is weird: if the amount is more than 15, you return "1111" appended to the representation for the remainder.  For instance, 20 would return as binary(5) followed by "1111", or "1011111", which is decidedly wrong.  Even stranger, it appears that *any* multiple of 15 will return "11110000", since that clause (== 15) overwrites any prior value of **b**.

I suggest that you analyze and simplify the logic.  There should be two cases:

- (BASE)  If number == 0, return '0'
- (RECUR) return ['1' (for odd) else '0'] + binary(number / 2)

You also need a top-level wrapper that checks the string length, padding out to 4 digits if needed.  If the "wrapper" logic doesn't fit your design ideas, then drop it, and work only with the **b** parameter ... but then quit returning values in your other branches, since you don't use them.

Does this get you moving?

Comment: Yes thank you! I am now storing b, and it is working correctly.

Comment: Regarding the logic for the binary numbers this is the correct logic based on the assignment, but thanks for your tips!

Comment: Great!  Please remember to accept your favourite answer, so Stack Overflow can properly retire the question ... even if you have to write it yourself.